# Wait until app gets authorization with SpotifyAPI-Net 5.1.1

Tags: c#, .net, spotify, spotify-app

I want my app to first get authorization and then do something with it, e.g. display user's name. The following code returns an error.

```
SpotifyWebApi api;

// (1) Get authorization (code from the official guide)
AuthorizationCodeAuth auth = new AuthorizationCodeAuth(
                "http://localhost:4002",
                "http://localhost:4002",
                Scope.UserReadPrivate | Scope.UserReadEmail
);

auth.AuthReceived += async (sender, payload) =>
{
    auth.Stop();
    Token token = await auth.ExchangeCode(payload.Code);
    api = new SpotifyWebAPI()
    {
        TokenType = token.TokenType,
        AccessToken = token.AccessToken
    };
};
auth.Start();
auth.OpenBrowser();

// (2) Get user's data
PrivateProfile apiUser = api.GetPrivateProfile();
Console.WriteLine(apiUser.DisplayName);
```

The problem is that the `(2)` code executes before it obtains the necessary authorization that `(1)` should provide, therefore, `api.GetPrivateProfile()` returns `null`. What should I do?

Comment: check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007228/how-to-call-the-spotify-api-from-c-sharp

Comment: @arc-menace Thanks for linking, but, unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem.